# Header position: fixed

Tags: html, css, header, fixed-header-tables

I would like to know if by any chance I can have a fixed header still at the screen when I scroll down and how can I do it?

I tried to add to the CSS `position: fixed;` in the `.header.dark` class but it's breaking the template.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us your code, show us what you've tried. Setting the `position: fixed` is usually done as the user scrolls past the element in question

Answer (score 0):

Should work OK. Try this:

```
<div class="header">This is the header</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:blue;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the two classes in your css code with a space.  From this:

```
.header.dark {
//fixed position
}
```

To this:

```
.header .dark {
// fixed position
}
```

I don't know what your code looks like but if you're trying to do something like this

```
<h1 class="three four">Double Class</h1>
```

then your css would look like this

```
.three.four { color: red; }
```

But if you're trying to do something like this

```
<div class="header">
<div class="dark">Stay at top</div>
</div>
```

then your css would look like this

```
.header .dark { position:fixed; }
```

Here's a good reference: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/